# JAXB: How to always include xsi:type for elements of type that has subtypes?

Tags: java, jaxb, xsitype

Let's assume following schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="User">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="SpecialUser">
    <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="User">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="speciality" type="xs:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="UserContainer">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="user" type="User"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now when I serialize:

```
new UserContainer()
    .withUser(
        new SpecialUser()
            .withName("name")
            .withSpeciality("speciality")
    )
```

I got:

```
...
<user xsi:type="SpecialUser">
    <name>name</name>
    <speciality></speciality>
</user>
...
```

However when I serialize:

```
new UserContainer()
    .withUser(
        new User()
            .withName("name")
    )
```

I got:

```
...
<user>
    <name>name</name>
</user>
...
```

Is there a way to configure JAXB to include `xsi:type` in second example (despite being redundant)?

Comment: You could make the complex type `User` asbtract and only use extensions of it. That is, you would introduce a new type `NormalUser` for example.

Comment: I can't modify schema :(